# My Query won't stop running

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to delete with a select and I tried to follow the instructions in the others post.

Now, my query doesn't return an error but it won't stop running.

I have almost 120k lines in the table cours, 120k lines in the table liste_des_cours_has_cours and 30 lines in liste_des_cours

```
delete from cours where Id_cours in 
(
    select cours.Id_cours from (select * from cours) as courssub1 
    where Id_cours not in 
    (
        select cours.Id_cours from (select * from cours) as courssub2 
        join (liste_des_cours_has_cours, liste_des_cours) 
        on courssub2.Id_cours = liste_des_cours_has_cours.Id_cours and liste_des_cours_has_cours.Id_liste_des_cours = liste_des_cours.Id_liste_des_cours
    )
);
```

Comment: From which table you want to delete ? and what is your table structures ? Please add it

Comment: i want to delete in the table cours

my tables cours and liste_des_cours are linked with liste_des_cours_has_cours

int the table liste_des_cours_has_cours, i have the PK and 2 foreign keys (the PK of the 2 others tables)

Comment: could you please add table structures ?and some sample data too ?

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: Try here http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler

Comment: So you want to delete all the records from **cours** where no matching record found in **liste_des_cours_has_cours** and **liste_des_cours** right ?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete all the records from cours where no matching record found in liste_des_cours_has_cours and liste_des_cours

Comment: create table cours(

 Id_cours int primary key auto_increment not null,
    someData int
);

create table liste_des_cours(

 Id_liste_des_cours int primary key auto_increment not null,
    someDate int

);

create table liste_des_cours_has_cours(

 Id_liste_des_cours_has_cours int primary key auto_increment not null,
    Id_cours int not null,
    Id_liste_des_cours int not null,
    CONSTRAINT toto FOREIGN KEY (Id_cours) REFERENCES cours(Id_cours),
    CONSTRAINT tata FOREIGN KEY (Id_liste_des_cours) REFERENCES liste_des_cours(Id_liste_des_cours)
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
delete c 
from liste_des_cours_has_cours a inner join liste_des_cours b 
on a.Id_liste_des_cours = b.Id_liste_des_cours 
right join cours c 
on c.Id_cours = a.Id_cours
where a.Id_cours is null;
```

Check here [Demo](http://rextester.com/TUVS69237)

Comment: You are using Sub query which always slower then the joins, you can read more about https://www.quora.com/Why-might-a-join-on-a-subquery-be-slow-How-might-you-speed-it-up